# What is IdentityPart in Orchard CMS good for?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I havent found any mention in Orchard documentation about IdentityPart despite it being used in some main modules like Comments. I took a look at some relevant sources, but it didn't help me to fully understand it's purpose.

So what's it for and when should I use it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is part of the import/export feature. In order to be able to move contents around servers reliably and in a repeatable way that takes into account updated and new items, we need a way to identify content items that's not just a simple id. Some contents have a path but not all types do (widgets, users, etc.). The export/import hooks for any part can participate in building the id of the item and in recognizing it on import. The routable part for example implements the use of path. But for those types that do not have routable, you can add the IdentityPart to fulfill that role. The id that gets exported in the end is a composite of all contributed ids.
Makes sense?